# Net::FTP having trouble uploading ZIP-archives?

Tags: perl, ftp, cpan

I'm trying to build a perl-script which zips a directory and uploads it to an FTP-server. I already got the zipping-part working, but unfortunately the ZIP-files always get 'destroyed', when uploaded to the FTP-Server (error when opening: 'Unexpected end of archive').

Am I doing something wrong here?

```
my $ftp = Net::FTP->new($host, Debug => 0) or die "Couldn't connect to $host: $!";
$ftp->binary();
$ftp->login($user, $password) or die "Couldn't login: $!";
$stat = $ftp->put($filename) or die "Couldn't upload file: $!";
```

Comment: Can you read the files on the server where you created them?

Comment: Try to set the transfer mode after login in to the server. I donno if it will help you...

Comment: Is the filehandle closed/flushed after writing/creating the zip file?

Comment: I suggest to close this, obviously the OP gave up and moved to somewhere else

Comment: What kailash19 said, also change debug to 1 if moving $ftp->binary to after login doesn't fix your problem.